# apply pixel shader with WinRT's Windows.Graphics.Capture

Tags: c#, c++, windows-runtime, shader, directx

The continuation of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68997008/can-we-apply-shader-on-transparent-window#comment122177532_68997008), I am able to find a way to capture a live screen without own window with help of WinRT's Windows.Graphics.Capture. I can concentrate directly on a particular window handle to get live capture. now, the problem with this approach is I am not able to apply pixel shader. The question [Applying HLSL Pixel Shaders to Win32 Screen Capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61515500/applying-hlsl-pixel-shaders-to-win32-screen-capture) having the same requirement but the answer to that question is not solving my problem.

Code with more information:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "SimpleCapture.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <dxgi1_2.h>
#include <sal.h>
#include <new>
#include <warning.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>
#include "PixelShader.h"

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::System;
using namespace Windows::Graphics::Capture;
using namespace Windows::Graphics::DirectX;
using namespace Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Numerics;
using namespace Windows::UI;
using namespace Windows::UI::Composition;

using namespace DirectX;

typedef struct _VERTEX
{
    DirectX::XMFLOAT3 Pos;
    DirectX::XMFLOAT2 TexCoord;
} VERTEX;

//
// A vertex with a position and texture coordinate
//
SimpleCapture::SimpleCapture(
    IDirect3DDevice const& device,
    GraphicsCaptureItem const& item)
{
    m_item = item;
    m_device = device;

    // Set up 
    m_d3ddevice = GetDXGIInterfaceFromObject<ID3D11Device>(m_device);
    m_d3ddevice->GetImmediateContext(m_d3dContext.put());
    auto size = m_item.Size();

    m_swapChain = CreateDXGISwapChain(
        m_d3ddevice,
        static_cast<uint32_t>(size.Width),
        static_cast<uint32_t>(size.Height),
        static_cast<DXGI_FORMAT>(DirectXPixelFormat::B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized),
        2);

    UINT Size = ARRAYSIZE(g_VS1);

    m_d3ddevice->CreateVertexShader(g_VS1, Size, nullptr, &m_VertexShader);

    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC Layout[] =
    {
        {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        {"TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
    };

    UINT NumElements = ARRAYSIZE(Layout);

    m_d3ddevice->CreateInputLayout(Layout, NumElements, g_VS1, Size, &m_InputLayout);

    m_d3dContext->IASetInputLayout(m_InputLayout);
    Size = ARRAYSIZE(g_main);


    // ADDED THIS
    Size = ARRAYSIZE(g_main);
    HRESULT hr = m_d3ddevice->CreatePixelShader(g_main, Size, nullptr, &m_PixelShader);


    // END OF ADDED CHANGES

    // Create framepool, define pixel format (DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM), and frame size. 
    m_framePool = Direct3D11CaptureFramePool::Create(
        m_device,
        DirectXPixelFormat::B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized,
        2,
        size);
    m_session = m_framePool.CreateCaptureSession(m_item);
    m_frameArrived = m_framePool.FrameArrived(auto_revoke, { this, &SimpleCapture::OnFrameArrived });
}
// Start sending capture frames
void SimpleCapture::StartCapture()
{
    CheckClosed();
    m_session.StartCapture();
}

ICompositionSurface SimpleCapture::CreateSurface(
    Compositor const& compositor)
{
    CheckClosed();
    return CreateCompositionSurfaceForSwapChain(compositor, m_swapChain.get());
}

// Process captured frames
void SimpleCapture::Close()
{
    auto expected = false;
    if (m_closed.compare_exchange_strong(expected, true))
    {
        m_frameArrived.revoke();
        m_framePool.Close();
        m_session.Close();

        m_swapChain = nullptr;
        m_framePool = nullptr;
        m_session = nullptr;
        m_item = nullptr;
    }
}

void SimpleCapture::OnFrameArrived(
    Direct3D11CaptureFramePool const& sender,
    winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const&)
{
    auto newSize = false;

    {
        auto frame = sender.TryGetNextFrame();
        auto frameContentSize = frame.ContentSize();

        //if (frameContentSize.Width != m_lastSize.Width ||
        //    frameContentSize.Height != m_lastSize.Height)
        //{
        //    // The thing we have been capturing has changed size.
        //    // We need to resize our swap chain first, then blit the pixels.
        //    // After we do that, retire the frame and then recreate our frame pool.
        //    newSize = true;
        //    m_lastSize = frameContentSize;
        //    m_swapChain->ResizeBuffers(
        //        2,
        //        static_cast<uint32_t>(m_lastSize.Width),
        //        static_cast<uint32_t>(m_lastSize.Height),
        //        static_cast<DXGI_FORMAT>(DirectXPixelFormat::B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized),
        //        0);
        //}

        /*auto d3dDevice = GetDXGIInterfaceFromObject<ID3D11Device>(m_device);
        d3dDevice->GetImmediateContext(m_d3dContext.put());*/

        {
            auto frameSurface = GetDXGIInterfaceFromObject<ID3D11Texture2D>(frame.Surface());

            com_ptr<ID3D11Texture2D> backBuffer;
            check_hresult(m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, guid_of<ID3D11Texture2D>(), backBuffer.put_void()));

            m_d3ddevice->CreateRenderTargetView(backBuffer.get(), NULL, &m_RTV);

            // ADDED THIS
            D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC txtDesc = {};
            txtDesc.MipLevels = txtDesc.ArraySize = 1;
            txtDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
            txtDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
            txtDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
            txtDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;

            //auto d3dDevice = GetDXGIInterfaceFromObject<ID3D11Device>(m_device);

            ID3D11Texture2D* tex;
            m_d3ddevice->CreateTexture2D(&txtDesc, NULL,
                &tex);
            frameSurface.copy_to(&tex);

            ID3D11ShaderResourceView* srv_1;
            m_d3ddevice->CreateShaderResourceView(
                tex,
                nullptr,
                &srv_1
            );

            auto texture = srv_1;
            m_d3dContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &texture);
            // END OF ADDED CHANGES

            // Create the sample state
            D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC SampDesc;
            RtlZeroMemory(&SampDesc, sizeof(SampDesc));
            SampDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
            SampDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
            SampDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
            SampDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
            SampDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
            SampDesc.MinLOD = 0;
            SampDesc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;
            m_d3ddevice->CreateSamplerState(&SampDesc, &m_SamplerLinear);

            D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC FrameDesc;
            tex->GetDesc(&FrameDesc);

            D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC ShaderDesc;
            ShaderDesc.Format = FrameDesc.Format;
            ShaderDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
            ShaderDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = FrameDesc.MipLevels - 1;
            ShaderDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = FrameDesc.MipLevels;
            // Vertices for drawing whole texture
            VERTEX Vertices[NUMVERTICES] =
            {
                {XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 1.0f)},
                {XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f)},
                {XMFLOAT3(1.0f, -1.0f, 0), XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f)},
                {XMFLOAT3(1.0f, -1.0f, 0), XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f)},
                {XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f)},
                {XMFLOAT3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0), XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 0.0f)},
            };
            // Create new shader resource view
            ID3D11ShaderResourceView* ShaderResource = nullptr;
            m_d3ddevice->CreateShaderResourceView(tex, &ShaderDesc, &ShaderResource);
            // Set resources
            UINT Stride = sizeof(VERTEX);
            UINT Offset = 0;
            m_d3dContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_RTV, nullptr);
            m_d3dContext->VSSetShader(m_VertexShader, nullptr, 0);
            m_d3dContext->PSSetShader(m_PixelShader, nullptr, 0);
            m_d3dContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &ShaderResource);
            m_d3dContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &m_SamplerLinear);
            m_d3dContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
            D3D11_BUFFER_DESC BufferDesc;
            RtlZeroMemory(&BufferDesc, sizeof(BufferDesc));
            BufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
            BufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(VERTEX) * NUMVERTICES;
            BufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
            BufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
            D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
            RtlZeroMemory(&InitData, sizeof(InitData));
            InitData.pSysMem = Vertices;

            ID3D11Buffer* VertexBuffer = nullptr;

            // Create vertex buffer
            m_d3ddevice->CreateBuffer(&BufferDesc, &InitData, &VertexBuffer);


            m_d3dContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &VertexBuffer, &Stride, &Offset);
            // Draw textured quad onto render target
            //m_d3dContext->CopyResource(backBuffer.get(), tex);
            m_d3dContext->Draw(NUMVERTICES, 0);
            // 
            //m_d3dContext->CopyResource(backBuffer.get(), frameSurface.get());
            //m_d3dContext->DrawAuto();
        }
    }

    DXGI_PRESENT_PARAMETERS presentParameters = { 0 };
    m_swapChain->Present1(1, 0, &presentParameters);
}
```

few additional links:

- Here is complete code [Screen capture for HWND](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/blob/master/cpp/ScreenCaptureforHWND/README.md)
- Ready to move to c# in case its easy in C# [WPF Screen Capture](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/blob/master/dotnet/WPF/ScreenCapture/README.md)

Please let me know any changes required in above code.

Comment: something invalid i am trying?

Comment: There are some problems: (1) In the code above you include `PixelShader.h` which is missing; (2) in the current version of the code the `m_d3ddevice` is undeclared, etc. If you could share the complete code with your changes that compiles and has all necessary resources (shaders, etc.), this could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything was correct except the copy resource call was missing once the new frame arrives.

```
m_d3dContext->CopyResource(m_SharedSurf, frameSurface.get());
```

pasting complete source code if someone wants to refer.

```
//*********************************************************
//
// Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved.
// This code is licensed under the MIT License (MIT).
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED “AS IS”, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, 
// INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, 
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. 
// IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, 
// DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, 
// TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH 
// THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
//
//*********************************************************

#include "pch.h"
#include "SimpleCapture.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <dxgi1_2.h>
#include <sal.h>
#include <new>
#include <warning.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>
#include "PixelShader.h"

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::System;
using namespace Windows::Graphics::Capture;
using namespace Windows::Graphics::DirectX;
using namespace Windows::Graphics::DirectX::Direct3D11;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Numerics;
using namespace Windows::UI;
using namespace Windows::UI::Composition;

using namespace DirectX;

typedef struct _VERTEX
{
    DirectX::XMFLOAT3 Pos;
    DirectX::XMFLOAT2 TexCoord;
} VERTEX;

//
// A vertex with a position and texture coordinate
//
SimpleCapture::SimpleCapture(
    IDirect3DDevice const& device,
    GraphicsCaptureItem const& item,
    HWND const& drawingHandle)
{
    m_item = item;
    m_device = device;
    m_WindowHandle = drawingHandle;

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    m_3dDevice = GetDXGIInterfaceFromObject<ID3D11Device>(m_device);
    m_3dDevice->GetImmediateContext(m_d3dContext.put());

    // Get DXGI factory
    IDXGIDevice* DxgiDevice = nullptr;
    hr = m_3dDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&DxgiDevice));  
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        assert(false);
    }

    IDXGIAdapter* DxgiAdapter = nullptr;
    hr = DxgiDevice->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&DxgiAdapter));
    DxgiDevice->Release();
    DxgiDevice = nullptr;
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        assert(false);
    }

    hr = DxgiAdapter->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory2), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&m_Factory));
    DxgiAdapter->Release();
    DxgiAdapter = nullptr;
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        assert(false);
    }

    // Get window size
    RECT WindowRect;
    GetClientRect(m_WindowHandle, &WindowRect);
    UINT Width = WindowRect.right - WindowRect.left;
    UINT Height = WindowRect.bottom - WindowRect.top;

    // Create swapchain for window
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 SwapChainDesc;
    RtlZeroMemory(&SwapChainDesc, sizeof(SwapChainDesc));

    SwapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL;
    SwapChainDesc.BufferCount = 2;
    SwapChainDesc.Width = Width;
    SwapChainDesc.Height = Height;
    SwapChainDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    SwapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    SwapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    SwapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    hr = m_Factory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(m_3dDevice.get(), m_WindowHandle, &SwapChainDesc, nullptr, nullptr, &m_SwapChain);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        assert(false);
    }

    // Disable the ALT-ENTER shortcut for entering full-screen mode
    hr = m_Factory->MakeWindowAssociation(m_WindowHandle, DXGI_MWA_NO_ALT_ENTER);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        assert(false);
    }

    // Create shared texture
    hr = CreateSharedSurf();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        assert(false);
    }
    // Make new render target view
    hr = MakeRTV();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        assert(false);
    }
    // Set view port
    hr = SetViewPort(Width, Height);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        assert(false);
    }
    // Create the sample state
    D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC SampDesc;
    RtlZeroMemory(&SampDesc, sizeof(SampDesc));
    SampDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    SampDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
    SampDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
    SampDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
    SampDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
    SampDesc.MinLOD = 0;
    SampDesc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;
    hr = m_3dDevice->CreateSamplerState(&SampDesc, &m_SamplerLinear);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        assert(false);
    }

    // Create the blend state
    D3D11_BLEND_DESC BlendStateDesc;
    BlendStateDesc.AlphaToCoverageEnable = FALSE;
    BlendStateDesc.IndependentBlendEnable = FALSE;
    BlendStateDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendEnable = TRUE;
    BlendStateDesc.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
    BlendStateDesc.RenderTarget[0].DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
    BlendStateDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
    BlendStateDesc.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ONE;
    BlendStateDesc.RenderTarget[0].DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ZERO;
    BlendStateDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendOpAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
    BlendStateDesc.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;
    hr = m_3dDevice->CreateBlendState(&BlendStateDesc, &m_BlendState);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        assert(false);
    }

    // Initialize shaders
    hr = InitShaders();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        assert(false);
    }
    // END OF ADDED CHANGES
    auto size = m_item.Size();

    // Create framepool, define pixel format (DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM), and frame size. 
    m_framePool = Direct3D11CaptureFramePool::Create(
        m_device,
        DirectXPixelFormat::B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized,
        2,
        size);
    m_session = m_framePool.CreateCaptureSession(m_item);
    m_frameArrived = m_framePool.FrameArrived(auto_revoke, { this, &SimpleCapture::OnFrameArrived });
}
//
// Initialize shaders for drawing to screen
//
HRESULT SimpleCapture::InitShaders()
{
    HRESULT hr;

    UINT Size = ARRAYSIZE(g_VS1);
    hr = m_3dDevice->CreateVertexShader(g_VS1, Size, nullptr, &m_VertexShader);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        assert(false);
        return hr;
    }

    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC Layout[] =
    {
        {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        {"TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
    };
    UINT NumElements = ARRAYSIZE(Layout);

    hr = m_3dDevice->CreateInputLayout(Layout, NumElements, g_VS1, Size, &m_InputLayout);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        assert(false);
        return hr;
    }

    m_d3dContext->IASetInputLayout(m_InputLayout);

    Size = ARRAYSIZE(g_main);
    hr = m_3dDevice->CreatePixelShader(g_main, Size, nullptr, &m_PixelShader);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        assert(false);
        return hr;
    }

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT SimpleCapture::SetViewPort(UINT Width, UINT Height)
{
    D3D11_VIEWPORT VP;
    VP.Width = static_cast<FLOAT>(Width);
    VP.Height = static_cast<FLOAT>(Height);
    VP.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    VP.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    VP.TopLeftX = 0;
    VP.TopLeftY = 0;
    m_d3dContext->RSSetViewports(1, &VP);
    return S_OK;
}

//
// Reset render target view
//
HRESULT SimpleCapture::MakeRTV()
{
    // Get backbuffer
    ID3D11Texture2D* BackBuffer = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = m_SwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&BackBuffer));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        assert(false);
        return hr;
    }
    // Create a render target view
    hr = m_3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(BackBuffer, nullptr, &m_RTV);
    BackBuffer->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        assert(false);
        return hr;
    }
    // Set new render target
    m_d3dContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_RTV, nullptr);

    return S_OK;
}

//
// Recreate shared texture
//
HRESULT SimpleCapture::CreateSharedSurf()
{
    auto size = m_item.Size();
    RECT magWindowRect;
    GetClientRect(m_WindowHandle, &magWindowRect); 

    // Create shared texture for all duplication threads to draw into
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC DeskTexD;
    RtlZeroMemory(&DeskTexD, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));
    DeskTexD.Width = static_cast<uint32_t>(size.Width);
    DeskTexD.Height = static_cast<uint32_t>(size.Height);
    DeskTexD.MipLevels = 1;
    DeskTexD.ArraySize = 1;
    DeskTexD.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    DeskTexD.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    DeskTexD.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    DeskTexD.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    DeskTexD.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    DeskTexD.MiscFlags = 0;

    HRESULT hr = m_3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&DeskTexD, nullptr, &m_SharedSurf);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        assert(false);
        return hr;
    }   
    return S_OK;
}

//
// 
// Start sending capture frames
void SimpleCapture::StartCapture(HWND drawingHandle)
{
    CheckClosed();
    m_session.StartCapture();
}

ICompositionSurface SimpleCapture::CreateSurface(
    Compositor const& compositor)
{
    CheckClosed();
    return CreateCompositionSurfaceForSwapChain(compositor, m_SwapChain);
}

// Process captured frames
void SimpleCapture::Close()
{
    auto expected = false;
    if (m_closed.compare_exchange_strong(expected, true))
    {
        m_frameArrived.revoke();
        m_framePool.Close();
        m_session.Close();

        m_SwapChain = nullptr;
        m_framePool = nullptr;
        m_session = nullptr;
        m_item = nullptr;
    }
}

void SimpleCapture::OnFrameArrived(
    Direct3D11CaptureFramePool const& sender,
    winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const&)
{
    auto newSize = false;
    {
        auto frame = sender.TryGetNextFrame();
        auto frameContentSize = frame.ContentSize();

        auto frameSurface = GetDXGIInterfaceFromObject<ID3D11Texture2D>(frame.Surface());

        m_d3dContext->CopyResource(m_SharedSurf, frameSurface.get());

        // Vertices for drawing whole texture
        VERTEX Vertices[NUMVERTICES] =
        {
            {XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 1.0f)},
            {XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f)},
            {XMFLOAT3(1.0f, -1.0f, 0), XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f)},
            {XMFLOAT3(1.0f, -1.0f, 0), XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 1.0f)},
            {XMFLOAT3(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0), XMFLOAT2(0.0f, 0.0f)},
            {XMFLOAT3(1.0f, 1.0f, 0), XMFLOAT2(1.0f, 0.0f)},
        };

        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC FrameDesc;
        m_SharedSurf->GetDesc(&FrameDesc);

        D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC ShaderDesc;
        ShaderDesc.Format = FrameDesc.Format;
        ShaderDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
        ShaderDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = FrameDesc.MipLevels - 1;
        ShaderDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = FrameDesc.MipLevels;

        // Create new shader resource view
        ID3D11ShaderResourceView* ShaderResource = nullptr;
        
        HRESULT hr = m_3dDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(m_SharedSurf, &ShaderDesc, &ShaderResource);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            assert(false);
        }

        // Set resources
        UINT Stride = sizeof(VERTEX);
        UINT Offset = 0;
        FLOAT blendFactor[4] = { 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f };
        m_d3dContext->OMSetBlendState(nullptr, blendFactor, 0xffffffff);
        m_d3dContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_RTV, nullptr);
        m_d3dContext->VSSetShader(m_VertexShader, nullptr, 0);
        m_d3dContext->PSSetShader(m_PixelShader, nullptr, 0);
        m_d3dContext->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &ShaderResource);
        m_d3dContext->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &m_SamplerLinear);
        m_d3dContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

        D3D11_BUFFER_DESC BufferDesc;
        RtlZeroMemory(&BufferDesc, sizeof(BufferDesc));
        BufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
        BufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(VERTEX) * NUMVERTICES;
        BufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
        BufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
        D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
        RtlZeroMemory(&InitData, sizeof(InitData));
        InitData.pSysMem = Vertices;

        ID3D11Buffer* VertexBuffer = nullptr;

        // Create vertex buffer
        hr = m_3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&BufferDesc, &InitData, &VertexBuffer);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            assert(false);
            ShaderResource->Release();
            ShaderResource = nullptr;
        }
        m_d3dContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &VertexBuffer, &Stride, &Offset);

        m_d3dContext->Draw(NUMVERTICES, 0);

        VertexBuffer->Release();
        VertexBuffer = nullptr;

        // Release shader resource
        ShaderResource->Release();
        ShaderResource = nullptr;

        DXGI_PRESENT_PARAMETERS presentParameters = { 0 };
        m_SwapChain->Present1(1, 0, &presentParameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: please feel free to ping me for complete code